# Android Security: How to check if C++ string constants are obfuscated when using ProGuard and DexGuard?

Tags: android, c++, proguard, dexguard

Context: We are putting some keys that does not expect any future changes or updates unless got compromise, originally these keys are in the server side but for this specific project we will not rely from REST API. We decided to put these keys in C++ and consuming it using JNI.

Currently we are now trying to decompile the APKs

- Debug/Release with ProGuard
- Debug/Release with DexGuard + ProGuard
- Debug/Release without obfuscation tool

Our question is where to locate and verify if the string constants in the C++ code is properly obfuscated, some says it can be found in `.so` files but cannot find it in the decompiled APK using JADX.

Comment: @Lino I haven't check that task again, will mark it as answer or put comments of the result once I resume. Thanks by the way for taking time answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an `apk` file, you can for instance:

1. change the suffix of the file from `apk` to `zip`
2. unzip the file

Now, `.so` files are usually located inside the `lib` folder and in particular inside subfolders that matches the different architectures (like for instance armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64 etc).

`.so` files cannot be decompiled with JADX since this tool is able to convert dex files into java source files instead.

My suggestion is to perform a simple search for the keys inside the files and if you don't find them you can try to decompile the .so file some c++ decompilers (but it might be a bit challenging).